# How to hook TCP/IP protocal in Windows 7, 8 using NDIS Hooking?

Tags: windows, networking

I used NdisRegisterProtocol function to hook TCP/IP protocal in NDIS 5.1(Windows XP) and it worked. 
In NDIS 6.0 and above, NdisRegisterProtocol function is not supported and I tried NdisRegisterProtocolDriver function, but it doesn't work...
Thank you for your help!

Comment: You should post the code you have that doesn't work, so that we can see what exactly you've tried, and maybe try to figure out why it doesn't work. Your question as written isn't very useful to 1) anybody else having this same problem and 2) anybody who would be trying to help you.

Answer (score 0):

You should look at [Microsoft's guide on porting NDIS 5.0 drivers to NDIS 6.0,](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff570059(v=vs.85).aspx) specifically, the [initialization section](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff570036(v=vs.85).aspx) from the [Intermediate Driver](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff570036(v=vs.85).aspx) guide:

> 1) Call the  NdisMRegisterMiniportDriver function with the
>   NDIS_INTERMEDIATE_DRIVER flag set to register the driver's MiniportXxx
>   functions.
>   2) Call the  NdisRegisterProtocolDriver function to
>   register the driver's ProtocolXxx functions if the driver subsequently
>   binds itself to an underlying NDIS driver.
>   3) Call the
>   NdisIMAssociateMiniport function to inform NDIS about the association
>   between the driver's miniport upper edge and protocol lower edge.